# Get the outer class reference in a nested class

Tags: java

I am trying to get an outer class reference in a nested class. Basically, I have a class inside another, so when I try to use the keyword "this" it doesn't reference the parent.

```
public class A extends JPanel {
  public A() {
     ...
     options.add(new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("item") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                window.setOldPanel(this); // this is the ActionEvent, not what I want (the outer class reference)
            }
        }
     )))
  }
}
```

Is there any way to do this without creating an instance of the parent in the nested?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `A.this`, which properly refers to the `A` `this`.